# Sorting out dependency injection in Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

if my understanding of typescript is correct, for the piece of code below, we are informing the class ContactusPage that it's constructor will receive two arguments, one will be of type NavController and other of type FormBuilder.

```
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
@Page({
  templateUrl: '...'
})
export class ContactusPage {
   constructor(nav: NavController, fb: FormBuilder) {
     this.contactForm = fb.group({
       name: ['',],
     });
     this.nav = nav;
   }
}
```

This is part of ionic code. When this ionic page is loaded, nowhere do we instantiate the ContactUsPage class with something like

```
 new ContactUsPage(navControllerInstance, FormBuilderInstance)
```

My confusion is that, we are informing this class to expect arguments of these types, nowhere do i see them being passed. how so ?

Comment: Because it's angular that calls the constructor for you, and injects the two dependencies it needs. That's the principle of DI.

Comment: @JBNizet I get that. For DI to function, there needs to be instances available and registered with angular framework. I do not see that happening anywhere

Comment: @SMV you have missed import `NavController`, add this line in your code `import {NavController} from './path/NavController';`

Comment: They (or rather, their provider, which allow creating them when needed), are registered by the angular bootstrap method, and by the decorators on the components: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

You register providers in the decorators `@Page()`, `@App()` (I'm not using Ionic and I don't know what decorators exist there, but I think to remember seeing these in questions). This is the information for DI how to create instances if requested.

```
@App({
  ...
  providers: [NavController]
)}
```